# How to add a custom separator to UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please spare sometime as this is a long explanation

I have a `UIViewController` which consists of a `UIButton` and a `UITableView` which loads different types of `UITableViewCell`s with Identifier `Cell1` and `Cell2`, on event `touchUpInside` of the button. I m using storyboard.

The separator for both cells are customized.

`Cell1` has a separator that occupies the entire width of cell and 1 pixel height at the bottom of the cell.

Whereas `Cell2` has a separator which has offset of 5 pixels from the cell, both left and right.

Each time the button outside the `tableView` is clicked the `tableViewCell`s are swapped, based on the cell identifier.

Initially the `tableView` occupies the complete width of `viewController` and consists of Cell1,  but the the button is tapped , `tableViewCell`s are changed to Cell2 and the frame of the `tableView` is Changed, The width is reduced by 10 and x-origin is increased by 5.

But when this happens, the separator of `Cell2` is 5 pixels away from the cell on right but on the left it is away by 5 pixel.
This happens for all `Cell2` which is loaded with data, and the cells which has no data the frame is changed appropriately.

But the cell after that has the width of `Cell1` (larger width)

```
-(void)setSeperatorStyleForTableView :(UITableViewCell *)cell //this is called in cellForRowAtIndex 
{
   //cell- type of cell(Cell1 or Cell2)

     CGRect seperatorFrame;
    UIImageView *seperatorImage;

    seperatorFrame = [self setSeperatorFrame:cell];

    if(firstCellToBeLoaded)//BOOL used to change the button text and load appropriate cells
    {
        seperatorImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table_row         
                                                                            2.png"]];
    }
    else
    {

        seperatorImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage   
                                                  imageNamed:@"table_row.png"]];
    }
    seperatorImage.frame = seperatorFrame;
    seperatorImage.autoresizingMask = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:seperatorImage];

}

//set the customized separator frame

-(CGRect)setSeperatorFrame :(UITableViewCell *)cell
{

    CGRect seperatorFrame;
    seperatorFrame.size.height = 1.0;
    seperatorFrame.origin.y = cell.frame.origin.y + (cell.frame.size.height - 1.0);

    if(firstCellToBeLoaded)
    {
        seperatorFrame.origin.x = cell.frame.origin.x ;
        seperatorFrame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width;
    }
    else
    {
        seperatorFrame.origin.x = cell.frame.origin.x + 5.0;
        seperatorFrame.size.width = cell.frame.size.width -10.0;

    }

    return seperatorFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can add `tableView`'s standard separator line, and add your custom line at the top of each cell.

In following code Change **hight/width/color/image** of `UIView` for set your separatorLine.

The easiest way to add custom separator is to add simple `UIView` of 1px height:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];/// change size as you need.
separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];// you can also put image here
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

**This code might solve your problem :)**

Comment: In general, this works. However, it breaks when the cell is selected/highlighted because then the `backgroundColor` in all the subviews is reset to transparent. Instead of `backgroundColor`, it's better to create a simple `UIView` subclass which will fill itself with the given color in `drawRect:`. Also, the separator can't go into the `contentView` (because of delete button, accesory views etc.). It must go directly to the cell.

Comment: @Sulthan - You can also put image instead of color, i also mentioned it in my answer's comment :) Thanks :)

Comment: Last cell doesn't add a line with this

Comment: @Mittchel - If you want to cover last cell separator line then need to change Y axis of separatorLineView 0 to cell.heigh-1

Answer (score 2):

Right way to do this would be to have the separator with in the cell class, subclass UITableViewCell if you haven't add a separator image variable there and on each cell creation you can just change the image and the frame rather than adding that on each redraw. If you require a code for this i can supply that as well. Currently when the cell is redrawn it already has the image u added last time and you just adding that again, either you remove that in -prepareForReuse method or just do as i explained above.

```
***** Custom Cell *****
//
//  CustomCell.m
//  Custom
//
//  Created by Syed Arsalan Pervez on 2/8/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SAPLogix. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _separatorImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:_separatorImage];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    _separatorImage.image = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_separatorImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Using the above cell in the view controller.

```
***** Test View Controller *****
//
//  TestViewController.m
//  Custom
//
//  Created by Syed Arsalan Pervez on 2/8/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 SAPLogix. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TestViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

#warning TODO: set the image name here
    _separatorImage1 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@""] retain];
    _separatorImage2 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@""] retain];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *_identifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:_identifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:_identifier] autorelease];
    }

    //Set Separator Image Here
    //Preload the image so it doesn't effect the scrolling performance
    CGRect frame = cell.contentView.frame;
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.separatorImage.image = _separatorImage1;
            cell.separatorImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(frame)-1, frame.size.width, 1);
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.separatorImage.image = _separatorImage2;
            cell.separatorImage.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x+5, CGRectGetMaxY(frame)-1, frame.size.width-10, 1);
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_separatorImage1 release];
    [_separatorImage2 release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way... hope this might help.

```
//
//  UITableViewCell+MyAdditions.h
//
//  Created by Roberto O. Buratti on 19/02/14.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITableViewCell (MyAdditions)

@property (nonatomic,assign) UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle cellSeparatorStyle;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor *cellSeparatorColor;

@end

//
//  UITableViewCell+MyAdditions.m
//
//  Created by Roberto O. Buratti on 19/02/14.
//

#import "UITableViewCell+MyAdditions.h"

NSString *const kUITablewViewCellSeparatorLayerName = @"kUITablewViewCellSeparatorLayerName";

@implementation UITableViewCell (MyAdditions)

-(CALayer *)separatorLayer
{
    for (CALayer *sublayer in self.layer.sublayers)
    {
        if ([sublayer.name isEqualToString:kUITablewViewCellSeparatorLayerName])
            return sublayer;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(CALayer *)newSeparatorLayer
{
    CALayer *separatorLayer = [CALayer layer];
    separatorLayer.name = kUITablewViewCellSeparatorLayerName;
    separatorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height - 1, self.bounds.size.width, 1);
    separatorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:separatorLayer];
    return separatorLayer;
}

-(UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle)cellSeparatorStyle
{
    CALayer *separatorLayer = [self separatorLayer];
    if (separatorLayer == nil)
        return UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    else
        return UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
}

-(void)setCellSeparatorStyle:(UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle)separatorStyle
{
    CALayer *separatorLayer = [self separatorLayer];
    switch (separatorStyle)
    {
        case UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone:
            [separatorLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
            break;
        case UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine:
            if (separatorLayer == nil)
                separatorLayer = [self newSeparatorLayer];
            break;
        default:
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) reason:@"Unsupported separatorStyle" userInfo:nil];
            break;
    }
}

-(UIColor *)cellSeparatorColor
{
    CALayer *separatorLayer = [self separatorLayer];
    return [UIColor colorWithCGColor:separatorLayer.backgroundColor];
}

-(void)setCellSeparatorColor:(UIColor *)separatorColor
{
    CALayer *separatorLayer = [self separatorLayer];
    if (separatorLayer == nil)
        separatorLayer = [self newSeparatorLayer];
    separatorLayer.backgroundColor = separatorColor.CGColor;
}

@end
```

Now you can do things like

```
UITableViewCell *cell = ...
cell.cellSeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
cell.cellSeparatorColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Comment: Worth noticing, that if instead of `cellSeparatorStyle` the name `separatorStyle` is used for the property, the cell will draw its own weird separators no matter what. It's essential not to create such a property on your `UITableViewCell` descendant.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, usually there's two ways to do this, either create a `CALayer` or a `UIView` separator of 1px and add it to `contentView`.

Over time I've seen multiple projects do this differently, and sometimes, even multiple different ways in the *same* project. It's also easy to introduce bugs because of cell reuse and also, for proper rendering of pixel lines, one must incorporate the screen scale: `(1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)`.

I've created a [library](https://github.com/kgaidis/KGViewSeparators) that simplifies this to just a single method class, with no subclassing required.
https://github.com/kgaidis/KGViewSeparators

**Objective-C**:

`[view kg_show:YES separator:KGViewSeparatorTop color:[UIColor blackColor] lineWidth:KGViewSeparatorLineWidth(1.0) insets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15.0, 0, 15.0)];`

**Swift:**

`view.kg_show(true, separator: .Bottom, color:  UIColor.blackColor(), lineWidth: KGViewSeparatorLineWidth(1.0), insets: UIEdgeInsetsZero)`