# uitableviewCell Separator line

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6

Hi I'm new to ios development. I am developing an application in which I am using `UITableView`.
`Tableview` contains some cells with separator line and others without separator line.
Can any one please tell me how can I remove separator line for specific cell?

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width);
```

Above code works for `iOS 7`. How can I achieve this in `iOS6`?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you can accomplish this by adjusting the cell's frame to cover the separator. I'm not sure if there is a better way though.

Comment: Hide tableView's default separator line. I mean make your tableView without any separator then add an `UIView` with 1px height and add it at the bottom of your cell's `contentView`. Don't add it for cell where you want to hide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add a `UIView` with the same background color as you want your separator line to be at the top of your `UITableViewCell` layout, make its height one pixel (it will be the same as a line) and its width the same as your cell width (cell.frame.size.width). After this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just set `hidden` property of this to `YES` for the cell you don't want it to be shown and `hidden` = `NO` for those you want. It is a simple solution which will work in any iOS version. But if will add your custom separator don't forget to disable default separators for all tableview

Comment: Can't we set separator colour as and when required in cellForRowAtIndexPath??

Comment: Of course you can:). I just thought you want separator's color to be the same. Your separator is a `UIView` so just call: `[yourSeparator setBackgroundColor]`

Comment: How can we achieve this? Because we can set colour with tableview object and that will reflect to all separators, isn't it?

Comment: Look. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is calling for every cell. So you can put a condition there: `if(cellYouWantToBeWithSeparator){show separator} else {don't}.

Comment: we want it for specify cell only but this is applying for entire table  even though we check specific IndexPath

Comment: @ShitalTiwari you should also add else condition. As I said cells are reusing. If only add if(..) {//show} then after first scroll all you cells will be with separators. But if you add if(){//show} else {//hide} then your separator will be shown only for those indexpathes you want

Answer (score 0):

In order to have only specific cells with separator you have to draw separator lines for those cells. In my view set the separator style to none and then draw you custom separator for the desired cells.

You can follow [this link for custom separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767847/how-to-add-a-custom-separator-to-uitableviewcell) 
Basically what u need to do is add a custom view as follows:

```
UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];/// change size as you need.

separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];// you can also put image here
[cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
```

to set the separator style to none use:

```
     tableView.separatorStyle=UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```

Comment: This will remove separators for all cells. And the OP wants :"contains some cells with separator line and others without separator line"

Comment: exactly Alexander, I want some cells with separator line and some without separator line

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change the color of the separatorLine for this. But one thing is that if you want to make the adjacent cells as a single cell then this would not be the right approach. As this will make only the UI change.

The better approach would be to adjust the size of the cell and so that you get "single cellClick events for them".

you can use the delegate for this:-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```