# UITableView Row Seperator Design

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm trying to get a similar row separator design as the image posted below, but I don't really know how to make the end of both sides "fade out". Does anyone know how do this in Swift.

Image: http://tinyurl.com/o9poehx

I know it's not much information or any code, but this is all I have at the moment.

Comment: why dont you have a custom image that looks like the fadeout separator?

Comment: I'd have to make a lot of them for all screen designs. Could do that, but was hoping this can be done programmatically.

Comment: you can add a custom separator view, but if you want to make native separator view custom it is not possible

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I mean, you can add a custom image as a separator view , but you can apply effects to native separator view other than color

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a custom separator to UITableViewCell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767847/how-to-add-a-custom-separator-to-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CAGradientLayer` with 4 colors, the outer two having an alpha of 0. Add the sublayer to your cell class's view.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example?

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to find an example on how to use `CAGradientLayer` in Google.