# the last UITableViewCell don't have a separating line

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView , Every UITableViewCell  has  a separating line under the cell except the last one ,why the last cell don't have separating line,  how to show it.

Comment: It’s default UITableView behavior. You always can implement separators on your own.

Comment: In your TableCell, create a UIView with height = 1 or anything and add it to the bottom. Then make Seperator = None in sotyboard by navigating to tableview properties.

Comment: check this....fine answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767847/how-to-add-a-custom-separator-to-uitableviewcell/14768460

Comment: hide the default seperator and create custom cell with custom separator using UILable

Answer (score 0):

To show separator you must set FooterView. And Add to the footer 1 point height view with black color